# Swift giving Optional(3) instead of 3 for .toInt

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Trying to pull a number from a Field and keep getting Optional(number) instead of the number

```
@IBOutlet weak var years: UITextField!

@IBAction func calculateYear(sender: AnyObject) {

    var a = years.text.toInt()
    println(a)
}
```

if 3 is in the field getting `Optional(3)`

if I use `years.text` I get the right output but it is a string and I can's work with it.

using Xcode 6.1

Comment: What are you surprised? Look at the header: `func toInt() -> Int?` It's an Optional. What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the `toInt()` method returns an optional, to account for the case when the string is not convertible to an integer.

Just put that in an optional binding:

```
if let a = a {
    println(a)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`toInt()` returns an optional because the conversation to an integer can fail. Consider the case where the user enters something other than a number. When the user enters "Blah", what do you expect `toInt()` to return?

You need to conditionally unwrap the optional

```
if let a = years.text.toInt() {
    println(a)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found forced unwrapping by changing a to a! worked as well. thanks to all who tried to help.

Comment: This will make it very easy for a user to crash your app. Any non-integer text entry in that field and kaboom.